# Which condition is necessary and sufficient for $f^{-1}(f(C)) = C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: A \to B$ be a function and $f^{-1}(Y)$ the inverse of $Y \subseteq B$ under $f$. I want to find out which of the three conditions (injectivity, surjectivity, bijectivity) is sufficient and necessary, such that for all $C \subseteq A$ we have $f^{-1}(F(C)) = C$.

I already know that injectivity is sufficient and necessary for $f^{-1}(F(C)) \subseteq C$. Is it also the case for $=$? My guess is that bijectivity is needed but I can't sadly come up with a proof. This is where I need your help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Indeed $f^{-1}(f(C)) \supseteq C$ is trivially satisfied by all functions. To prove it, you have to show that for all $x \in C$, $f(x) \in f(C)$.

Comment: but which one of them is sufficient and necessary for $f^{-1}(f(C)) = C$? Injective again or bijective?

Comment: The equality $f^{-1}(f(C)) = C$ is equivalent to the inclusion $f^{-1}(f(C)) \subseteq C$! Hence, the correct answer is injectivity.

Answer (score 2):

As already observed, the inclusion $f^{-1}(f(C)) \supseteq C$ is always satisfied.

On the other hand, if $f$ is not an injective function then the strict inclusion may hold. For example, if you consider the function $f(x) = x^2$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $C = [0,+\infty)$, you see in a moment that $f^{-1}(f(C)) = f^{-1}([0,+\infty)) = \mathbb{R}$.

If $f$ is injective you can prove that equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: A\to B$, $S\subseteq A$. Then $S\subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$. Notice that this holds for **every** function, whether being one-to-one, whether being onto. (I skip the proof here.)

In other words, it says that if you send a set from domain into codomain, and then pull them back, the resulting set must contains the original set and may be larger  than that. Why there's a possibility that the "larger" condition arise? Since a function can send multiple value to one value. For example, you defined a function that $f(0)=100,~f(1)=100,~f(2)=100,~f(3)=100,~f(4)=100$. Then $f(\{0\})=\{100\}$(here $\{0\}$ is the set $S$ metioned above), and $f^{-1}(f(\{0\}))=f^{-1}(\{100\})=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. And you can notice here that the relation between $S$ and $f^{-1}(f(S))$, namely $\{0\}$ and $f^{-1}(f(\{0\}))$, is that $\{0\}\subseteq f^{-1}(f(\{0\}))$.

So when does $S=f^{-1}(f(S))$? Namely, when does $f^{-1}(f(S))\subseteq S$? According to the discussion above, we may guess that it is $f$ is one-to-one. We make rigourous proof here:

> Theorem: Let $f: A\to B$. $f$ is one-to-one if and
>    only if for every $S\subseteq A$, $S=f^{-1}(f(S))$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $f$ is one-to-one. Claim for every $S\subseteq A$, 
 $S=f^{-1}(f(S))$.

Let $S$ be any subset of $A$. We have known that $S\subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$ is always true. So we are left to show $f^{-1}(f(S))\subseteq S$. Let $x\in f^{-1}(f(S))$. Then by the definition(of inverse image), $f(x)\in f(S)$. Since $f(x)\in f(S)$, then by the definition(of image), there exists $x'\in S$ such that $f(x')=f(x)$. By the hypothesis that $f$ is one-to-one, $x'=x$. Since $x'\in S$, we get that $x\in S$. And we have shown that $f^{-1}(f(S))\subseteq S$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose for every $S\subseteq A$, 
 $S=f^{-1}(f(S))$. Claim $f$ is one-to-one.

To claim $f$ is one-to-one, the standard procedure is to show that for every $x_1,x_2\in A$, if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $x_1=x_2$. So we're going to do this.

Let $x_1,x_2\in A$. Suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $f(\{x_1\})=f(\{x_2\})$. Take the inverse image on both side, then $f^{-1}(f(\{x_1\}))=f^{-1}(f(\{x_2\}))$. By the hypothesis, we get that $\{x_1\}=\{x_2\}$, so $x_1=x_2$. And this is $f$'s being one-to-one.